# preg_replace <h2>'.'</h2> dot, full-stop within title not working, wrong regex? - PHP & Wordpress

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

I've been stressing over this for the last day and just cant seem to get the right preg_replace regex combination, as always any help id really appreciated.

My code is as follows, I just can't seem to target the . within the title, likely to be an ...

```
$content_title_spanned = preg_replace('/<h([1-6]{1})>\.<\/h\\1>/si', '<span class="full-stop">.</span>', $content);
```

Comment: Why do you have the double backslash in `<\/h\\1>`. It does not match `<h1>.</h1>`. Remove it and it matches.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: It's just from all the different combinations i've tried, the most simple is preg_replace('/<h2>(.*)<\/h2>/', '<span>.</span>', $content); obviously this will replace the entire <h2> but i'm looking to only wrap the . in a <span>, i;m running through the entire content of a Custom Field, Grabbing the H2's and wrapping any fullstops/periods within the <h2> with a span.

Comment: Following on from @marekful, you are allowing for 1-6 in the open, but only 1 in the close

Comment: Following on from my original comment and more focused match would be preg_replace('/<h2>([.])<\/h2>/', '<span>.</span>', $content); yet it still doesn't seem to find the '.', yet I get no errors, it just ignores it.

Comment: You are over looking it. Remove html tags with `strip_tags()` , then concatenate yourself `$string = "<h1>".$string."</h1>"` ....

Comment: I'm really sorry but I don't follow?

Comment: See http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php , this is well known fact, don't use regex on html (Because it often fails)! see https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/113237/when-you-should-not-use-regular-expressions ;)

Comment: strip_tags would be ok in situations when i'm dealing with just the title as a singular string but as it's being pulled from the WYSIWIG editor there will be other content as well, it's literally on the h2s i'm concerned with hence why I was using regex, and it's also for a single scenario, or am I getting the wrong end of the stick.

Comment: Make a live demo show us what output you get and what output you expect to get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a regex that finds the first `.` within header tags (`<h1>` to `<h6>`) and replaces the `.` with the HTML you specified. The trick is using `()` to capture the text before and after the period as well, and substituting those strings back in the replacement with `$1` and `$4`. I also use non-greedy capturing `*?` to ensure that if there are multiple `<h1>` matches in the string, it only matches the contents of the first one, not from the start of the first to the end of the last.

**Search regex**, with `isx` flags:

```regex
( <h([1-6])> .*? )
(\.)
( .*? <\/h\2> )
```

The `x` flag lets you write whitespace in the regex to make it clearer. If you prefer, you can write the above on one line, with less whitespace: `(<h([1-6])> .*?) (\.) (.*? <\/h\2>)`

**Replacement string**:

```
$1<span class="full-stop">.</span>$4
```

#### Example

[Online demo](https://regex101.com/r/DVSwSM/2)

```html
<h1>My <b>cool</b> book.</h1>
<p>test</p>
```

is changed into

```html
<h1>My <b>cool</b> book<span class="full-stop">.</span></h1>
<p>test</p>
```

Comment: Hi Rory, thanks so much, your solution got me there in the end! Legend. preg_replace('/(<h([2])>.*?)(\.)(.*?<\/h\2>)/', '$1<span class="full-stop">.</span>$4', $content);

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$content = '<h1>1.</h1>abcd<h2>2.</h2>abcd<h3>3.</h3><p>abcd</p><h4>4.</h4><h5>5.</h5><h6>6.</h6>';
$content_title_spanned = preg_replace('/(<h[1-6]>[^<]+)(.)(<\/h[1-6]>(?!.*<h.*|.*<\h.*)?)/', '$1<span class="full-stop">$2</span>$3$4', $content);
print_r($content_title_spanned);
?>
```

[**Live Demo**](https://onlinegdb.com/HyLeFg2iG)

Comment: Thanks for this but this doesn't actually target the '.' it wraps every word with a span, thank you though.

Comment: @PaulJackson just let me know by example what is the input and expected result

Comment: @PaulJackson updated , i was thinking that you need to replace them , actually yesterday someone asked closed question but with replacement